# Was Crewman Daniels' experience parallel to Archer's?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In Star Trek Enterprise, there was a character named crewman Daniels who travelled back in time from the 31th century to influence Captain Archer.

Daniels visited many times, and we saw his visits in a linear order. Visit 1. Visit 2. Visit 3. Etc.  But we were seeing Archer's time progression.

Did Daniels' 31th Century time progression run linearly with Archer's time?  For example, did time point 1 in the 31th century correspond with visit 1 in Archer's time? Then did time 2 in 31th century correspond with visit 2 for Archer?  I am asking if Daniels and Archer were experiencing the same order of events?

I seem to recall Daniels telling Archer about needing to clean up chaos in the 31th century that resulted from events in Archer's time. And I recall Daniels hiding in other centuries. ... But can someone shed light on whether Daniels was able to relate with Archer's linear experience?

Comment: A possible complication: Daniels survived *death*, possibly by the same kind of time manipulation Seven of Nine experienced (*Voyager* 5x24, "Relativity"), so events in his timeline might occur in parallel rather than in series.

Comment: I really never understood the temporal cold war if temporal shields prevent alterations in the timeline from affecting you (like we see in the year of hell episodes of voyager) then no faction should be able to do anything that would in any way damage another faction (presumably you would have a lot if not all assets equip with temporal shielding)

Comment: @revenant, perhaps temporal shields only protect you against changes in the timeline caused by the Krenim temporal incursion technology, not against changes caused by actual time travelers.

Comment: @Harry perhaps but if you cant protect yourself from alterations of the past there would be no way of telling which events were supposed to occur and which involved time travel shenanigans.  Then again wibbly wobbly timey wimey does not even begin to cover star trek theory of time travel

Comment: @revenant, I sort of imagine some kind of time scanners telling them about disturbances "before" the change reaches their time.  (You still have to invoke WWTW to explain why they can usually only send one ship to investigate, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

Daniel's first visit to Enterprise NX-01 was his last visit from 31st century point of view. After he revealed Archer that he was a time traveler, Silik killed him (Episode: Cold Front).

And yet, he reappeared in a later episode to took Archer 10 months back. When Archer expressed surprise on Daniel's survival saying he thought Silik killed him, he responded:

> he did...in a manner of speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory "you're not thinking 4th dimensionaly"

Canonically I do not believe it is brought up with that being said

it seems that time travel has some rules in the trek verse otherwise you would have things like person A goes back in time to do something person B stops them so person C goes back to try and help person A and person D goes to stop person C ad infitium

which to me suggests a linear existence for all parties each time Daniels saw Archer Daniels had advanced on his personal timeline

Incidentally it would probably be SOP that no agent goes back to a place they had previously been to prevent paradox situations as well as to prevent accidentally changing the outcomes of their previous missions